# Company publishing Standalone but not Consolidated financial results

Tags: stocks, india, stock-analysis, annual-report, nse-india

Some companies publish Standalone result time to time but not consolidated result.

Ex- ABC company is publishing Standalone quarterly results ,but not publishing consolidated result since last 2 years.

Should we stay away from these companies? Also is there some kind of policy by SEBI that says listed companies should publish their Standalone or Consolidated results?

Comment: From what I've read it is optional for quarterly results according to SEBI - you can read more [here](http://www.livemint.com/Money/7Yk966uVHfUeZ2wcJRsyUN/Sebi-to-make-financial-reporting-more-robust.html)

Comment: I don't think you mean consolidated. Consolidation occurs when an entity owns multiple entities and aggregates their assets, liabilities, income and expenses.

Answer (score 1):

> Should we stay away from these companies?

This is individuals choice and there is no generic answer. Not publishing consolidated results does not mean company is NOT good.

> Also is there some kind of policy by SEBI that says listed companies should publish their Standalone or Consolidated results?

As pointed out by Ross in comment, no it is not [mandatory](http://www.livemint.com/Money/7Yk966uVHfUeZ2wcJRsyUN/Sebi-to-make-financial-reporting-more-robust.html).